# Laravel, Routing Wildcards to filter and then controller

Tags: filter, controller, wildcard, laravel, routes

I am trying to capture a wildcard from URL and then first pass it to a filter then route to controller. I am not sure how to plot the question exactly but here is what I've tried so far.

```
Route::get('test/(:any?)', array('as' => 'testroute', 'uses' => 'test@result', 'before' => "test_filter:$1"));

Route::filter('test_filter', function($id = NULL)
{
    if($id)
    echo "This id is " . $id;    // Prints "This id is $1"
});
```

and

```
Route::get('test/(:any?)', array('as' => 'testroute', function($id = NULL)
{
    if($id)
        echo "this id is " . $id;    // Does not do anything
}, 'uses' => 'test@result'));
```

Basically, I want to check if there is an id appended to the URL and set a cookie if there is one. But regardless of the case, I want this route to be handled by a controller no matter if there is any id appended or not.

I have to do the same thing with so many routes so I'd prefer something like a filter rather than modifying the controller's codes.

I know that I can directly pass the wildcard element to a closure, or I can feed this as a parameter to any controller but in that case I'll have to modify the controller codes, which I can't at the moment.

Can I do it through filters ? or any other way in which i wont have to modify the controller codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an anonymous right after the before

```
Route::get('test/(:any?)',
    array(
       'as' => 'testroute',
       'uses' => 'test@result',
       'before' => "test_filter",
       function($my_cookie_value)
       {
          // Set cookie here
       }
    )
 );
```

Taken from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#filters)

Comment: Nope, The anonymous function does not do anything. It just apply the filter and then forward the route to controller. Also, I need to grab the value of wildcard inside filter or anonymous closure.

Comment: @Gufran updated the code again, passing the match to the anon function, see if that's working

Comment: No, it dont do anything. It looks like the anonymous functions is simply being ignored. By the way, I've read all the documentations over Laravel docs, apparently this is not possible like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a middleware http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware (or filter for older Laravel versions) and add the route/s into a group which has the middleware as you can see in here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-middleware.

The middleware will be executed before the route code, where you can add a logic to manage your cookie.

Comment: Thanks. Very much appreciated but this question is 2.5 years old. It usually show the date of posting under the question so try to check the date next time.